# Application doesn't resume on globally caught UnhandledExceptions

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, error-handling

I am catching exceptions globally and it's working fine except for the part that application doesn't resume on `UnhandledExceptions`.

I have read on MSDN that in order to allow dispatcher Exception to catch unhandled non UI exceptions, I need to do following two things, but I have no idea how to do that.

- Dispatch those exceptions to the main UI thread.
- Rethrow them on the main UI thread without handling them to allow  `DispatcherUnhandledException` to be raised.

My code:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
    }

    private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message, "Dispatcher Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        e.Handled = true;            
    }

    void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Unhandeled Exception Event", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens when a unhandled exception occurs? Application is shutting down or what?

Comment: It shows a message box like I defined and then it throws the exception , we can see from the VS and then application closes

Comment: There is no e.Handled property in `UnhandeledException`

Answer (score 0):

Don' know if this will help but to dispatch to the main UI thread you will need to call Invoke.

e.g. some sudo code if you are on the main form.

```
try
{
 ... stuff
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     this.Invoke(()=> throw ex));
}
```

If you are not on the main form then you will need to throw an event from where ever the error occurs and have something listening on the main form and then do the above in the method attached to the listener.

Comment: Do I need to add it in my all code or is there a way to do it globally

Comment: My gut feeling is that you'd have to add it in multiple places - can't think of a way to do it globally... p.s. if the answer helped at all please up vote

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> This event provides notification of uncaught exceptions. It allows the
>   application to log information about the exception **before the system
>   default handler reports the exception to the user and terminates the
>   application.**

(emphasize added)

So the `UnhandledException` event is only provided for logging information etc. It doesn't prevent the shutdown of the application.

However in Windows.Forms application you may consider this (same MSDN artice, scroll down):

> In applications that use Windows Forms, unhandled exceptions in the
>   main application thread cause the [Application.ThreadException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event to
>   be raised. If this event is handled, the default behavior is that the
>   unhandled exception **does not terminate the application**, although the
>   application is *left in an unknown state.*

(emphasize added).

Comment: But I am using WPF, and how do I catch unhandled exceptions globally? I don't want to write all my application code in try catch blocks

Comment: So I'm not sure what you are trying to do. You can not actually _handle_ exceptions at that point. When you only catch them at this stage, your app is already crashed. The only thing you could do here is display a nicer crash dialog than Microsoft's, but you can not recover your app. For proper error handling I don't think you can avoid to wrap the dangerous parts of your code in `try...catch` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me

```
        /// <summary>
        /// All Application Exception is Handled by this Event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Error Object</param>
        /// <param name="e">Error value</param>
        [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
        [SecurityCritical]
        private void Application_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                    WpfLogger.Log.Error(e.Exception.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: It also catches the `DispatcherUnhandledException` which are generated on UI Thread. I am looking solution `UnhandledException` Catching